# H1 tag inside text area

Tags: html, textarea

There is a activity stream webpart in my site where user can update the content and content gets updated in the activity stream instantly. I am using Textarea tag to capture the content. IF user inserts img tag, anchor(`<a>`) tag the behaviour is as expected. i.e. image is shown and the link too in activity stream. But if I enter some text in `<H1>` tag, there is no change. moreover if I enter the text containing all the heading tags from h1 to h6, all of them are rendered same.

Is the formating allowed in text area?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to worry about older browsers, I'd suggest using contentEditable attribute on a div element as this will allow you to  format your input in any way you like. Remember that it's only for browsers that support HTML5 though, so you would need to look into cross-browser compatibility.

```
<div contentEditable="true"></div>
```